# Don't show user location on click - JS

Tags: javascript, java, json

I have small problem with JavaScript. I wanted to finish be when user click on circle to show their location example:

[Screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3Zrq.jpg)

In that field, when user click on circle right, script need to locate user and display him his address.This is my code for that:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Location" id="autocomplete-input" value=""/>
<a href="#" class="get-current-location"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i></a>
```

Code for class="get-current-location":

```
<script>
        $(document).on("click",".get-current-city",function(t){getCurrentGeoLocation(function(t){null!=t.result&&setTimeout(function(){$(mainSearchLocationEle).val(t.result),$("#address_lat").length&&$("#address_lat").val(t.lat),$("#address_lng").length&&$("#address_lng").val(t.lng),$("#nearby-checkbox").length&&$("#nearby-checkbox").prop("checked",!0),$("#nearby-input").length&&$("#nearby-input").val("on")},500)})});
        </script>
```

Javascript code: *PS. I'm not sure is this JS for this field above...*

```
$(".location a , .loc-act").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
  $(".location input , .qodef-archive-places-search").val( response.city);

}, "jsonp");
```

Can anybody help me with this. I'm not good in Java but i will be thanksfull who help me.

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: I write. Im not good with JS, Java etc.. @epascarello

Comment: Can you show the actual code because you do not have an element with a class location and there is a syntax error with your click event.

Comment: I will edit now my question @epascarello

Comment: That is all of codes for get locations. @epascarello